# Not getting right Intent in the second Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to pass my custom Class in a bundle from an activity to another using an intent and putExtras() using this code:

```
public class MyFirstActivity extends ListActivity {

String selectedItem = "selectedItem";
String[] allItemNames;
CustomClass[] allItems = null;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_all_items);


    allItems = createItemsMethod(); //IsTooLongToPost


    CustomClass item = new CustomClass();
    String[] allItemNames = getAllTheNamesMethod(); //IsTooLongToPost


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.show_item_in_row, R.id.textview_item_row, allItemNames);


    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    // Do something when a list item is clicked
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    String value = (String) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MySecondActivity.class);
    Item currentItem = allItems[position];
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelable("Key", currentItem);
    intent.putExtras(b);

    startActivity(intent);
}}
```

The values in this intent are OK, but when I try to take them in my other activity, the intent is empty and the Extras are not there, my other activity has this code:

```
public class MySecondActivity extends Activity {


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.show_activity);
}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(b!=null){
        CustomClass item = b.getParcelable("Key");
    }
}}
```

This is the CustomClass

```
public class CustomClass implements Parcelable{

String name;
int id;
String description;
LinkedList<CustomClass> related;

String[] itemList;

// Other costructors and getters

public CustomClass(Parcel parcel) {
    name = parcel.readString();
    id = parcel.readInt();
    description = parcel.readString();
    related = null;

}

// Parcel Part

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(name);
    parcel.writeInt(id);
    parcel.writeString(description);
    parcel.writeTypedList(related);
}

public static Creator<CustomClass> CREATOR = new Creator<CustomClass>() {
    public CustomClass createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
        return new CustomClass(parcel);
    }

    public CustomClass[] newArray(int size) {
        return new CustomClass[size];
    }
};}
```

Any Idea why is this happening? Thanks

Comment: You're going to need to give more info.  Show the real code, and also show your custom class that implements Parcelable.

Comment: @DanielNugent I added all the code from the first activity, basically it makes a list, the second activity is made with the onListItemClick, but the intent i give in startActivity(intent) has all the correct info and the right extras, but when  I call it in the other activity they are gone, it's other intent. If it's needed I will add the CustomClass too, but i don't know if the Parceable is well implemented, I never did one that implements it before

Comment: @tylle Why aren't you using `Bundle`s to save your `CustomClass` stuff into it? It's pretty more handy than `Parcel`s.

Comment: @abforce you mean giving the intent the CustomClass attributes individually as extras instead of the whole class?

Comment: @tylle Nope, I just mean that you could serialize your class into a bundle and then put this bundle into the bundle of that intent. You can put bundle into bundles.

Comment: @abforce that's another option, but I guess that now I stumbled into this, I have to know why it's not working so I can sleep tonight

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement Parcelable in your class Anime and add unimplemented methos
Follow this link to learn how to implement it 
https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/account/Account.java

Comment: The putParceble method seems to work fine and the intent has my class as extra, but I will look at the link, maybe that's the problem as I never implemented one before, thank you

Comment: I implemented the same way as in the link but it didn't work, tried to had a String as extra instead of my class a didn't work either, so the problem has to be somewhere else

Comment: The way u put the object in intent and read it is correct, the problem is on the class Anime, u must implement as i tell u, hope this help

Comment: Show me how did you implement parcelable? put the class here

Comment: try to get theb bundle from intent in onCreateView

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an object from one activity to an another activity, you can use two approaches as per my knowledge.
One is making your Bean(class) **Parcelable** and other simple approach would be to make it **Serializable**.

**Using Serializable**
Suppose you want to pass an object of this class

```
public class CustomClass implements Serializable{
    //put your class member variable here and it's getters and setters
    }
```

Then from your first activity,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MySecondActivity.class);
//get the object of CustomClass which you want to pass
// let's say it's name is **customClassObject**

//Now pass it to the second activity
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,clickedMenuItemBean);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now in your Second Activity.Get the passes object of Custom class 
in intent.

```
CustomClass cc = (CustomClass) intent.getSerializableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
```